# Symfony2 SonataClassificationBundle querying from database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am trying to query a dynamic category sidebar and I am using the Sonata ClassificationBundle. I Have created a few categories(parent) and some subcategories(child). I am able to show the categories, however I cant understand how to query the subcategories under a specific category. I think i need to check if the category has children and display it? I have no idea how to do that without proper documentation..

This is the sidebar controller:

```
<?php

namespace Mp\ShopBundle\Controller;

use Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category;
use Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Model\CategoryInterface;
use Sonata\Component\Currency\CurrencyDetector;
use Sonata\Component\Product\Pool;
use Sonata\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductSetManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class SidebarController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @  Route("/hello/{name}")
     * @  Template()
     */
    public function sidebarAction()
    {
        $page        = $this->getRequest()->get('page', 1);
        $displayMax  = $this->getRequest()->get('max', 9);
        $displayMode = $this->getRequest()->get('mode', 'grid');
        $filter      = $this->getRequest()->get('filter');
        $option      = $this->getRequest()->get('option');

        if (!in_array($displayMode, array('grid'))) { // "list" mode will be added later
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('Given display_mode "%s" doesn\'t exist.', $displayMode));
        }

        $category = $this->retrieveCategoryFromQueryString();

        return $this->render('sidebar.html.twig', array(
            'display_mode' => $displayMode,         
            'category'   => $this->getCategoryManager()->findBy(
            array('parent' => 1 )),         
            'subcategory' => $this->getCategoryManager()->findBy(
            array('children' => true )),    ////// ERROR You cannot search for the association field 'Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category#children', because it is the inverse side of an association. Find methods only work on owning side associations."
            'provider'     => $this->getProviderFromCategory($category),
        ));
    }


             /*  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $products = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findAll();
               return $this->render('sidebar.html.twig',  array(
               'products'=>$products       
               )); */

    /**
     * Retrieve Category from its id and slug, if any.
     *
     * @return CategoryInterface|null
     */
    protected function retrieveCategoryFromQueryString()
    {
        $categoryId   = $this->getRequest()->get('category_id');
        $categorySlug = $this->getRequest()->get('category_slug');

        if (!$categoryId || !$categorySlug ) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->getCategoryManager()->findOneBy(array(
            'id'      => $categoryId,
            'enabled' => true,
        ));
    }
```

This is how I try to display the sidebar:

```
{% for categories in category %}

            {% for subcategories in subcategory %}

                <li class="subMenu"><a> {{ categories.name }} [{{ categories|length }}]</a>
                <ul>

                    <li><a href="{{ path('products') }}">{{ subcategories.name }} ({{ categories|length }})</a></li>

                </ul>
                </li>

            {% endfor %}

            {% endfor %}
```

The Category entity:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Sonata project.
 *
 * (c) Sonata Project <https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataClassificationBundle/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Model;

use Sonata\MediaBundle\Model\MediaInterface;

interface CategoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param $name
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function setName($name);

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string $name
     */
    public function getName();

    /**
     * Set enabled
     *
     * @param boolean $enabled
     */
    public function setEnabled($enabled);

    /**
     * Get enabled
     *
     * @return boolean $enabled
     */
    public function getEnabled();

    /**
     * Set slug
     *
     * @param integer $slug
     */
    public function setSlug($slug);

    /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return integer $slug
     */
    public function getSlug();

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     */
    public function setDescription($description);

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string $description
     */
    public function getDescription();

    /**
     * @param integer $position
     */
    public function setPosition($position);

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getPosition();

    /**
     * Add Children
     *
     * @param CategoryInterface $children
     * @param boolean           $nested
     */
    public function addChild(CategoryInterface $children, $nested = false);

    /**
     * Get Children
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $children
     */
    public function getChildren();

    /**
     * Set children
     *
     * @param $children
     */
    public function setChildren($children);

    /**
     * Return true if category has children
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasChildren();

    /**
     * Set Parent
     *
     * @param CategoryInterface $parent
     * @param boolean           $nested
     */
    public function setParent(CategoryInterface $parent = null, $nested = false);

    /**
     * Get Parent
     *
     * @return CategoryInterface $parent
     */
    public function getParent();

    /**
     * @param MediaInterface $media
     */
    public function setMedia(MediaInterface $media = null);

    /**
     * @return MediaInterface
     */
    public function getMedia();

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     */
    public function setContext(ContextInterface $context);

    /**
     * @return ContextInterface
     */
    public function getContext();
}
```

**MY IDEA**
Okay since all the parent categories have a parent_id of 1, i display them easily. The child categories have parent_id that is the same as the id of the parent category. Is it possible to somehow query this condition? Like parent_id = id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply use `getChildren()` on every parent category: the entity should be hydrated, so the query is already done for you.

Comment: Do you mean I should write categories.getChildren() and the subcategories will be displayed? Because I am getting an error: "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string". Or the getChildren method should be somewhere else? Sorry if the question is dumb but this is my first week with symfony. :(

Comment: It returns an array, so you'll need to use it inside an other for cycle

Comment: You saved my nerve system once again!